# Unable to move files having spaces in their name

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, filenames

I want to move files from one folder to another folder, my code is working fine when file name doesn't contain spaces but if there is a space in a file name then I am getting an error My Code is as follows :

```
find [folderName] -size +1k -type f -name \*.txt -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
      echo $file
      mv $file targetfolderName    
      done
```

**File Names**

sample 01.txt
test - copy 01.txt

Comment: [Use more quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
find [folderName] -size +1k -type f -name \*.txt -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
      echo $file
      mv "$file" targetfolderName    
      done
```